# MPDF is generating HTTP Error 500 for many rows

Tags: php, string, pdf, yii2, mpdf

In my PHP-MySQL application which is created using Yii2 framework, I have used mpdf (Version: 6.0) for generating PDF reports.

Everything was working fine until I have tried to generate a report which has a table around 50 rows and 32 columns. It is generating

```
'X' page isn’t working
'X' is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

But when I reduce the number of rows, the pdf is showing without any error. I have already double checked the html code of the pdf if it has any error, but no luck!

Here is the pdf format which is being generated for less number of rows.

[image: Generated report]

The lower table data is being sent using a string variable which contains all data. What is the problem? Memory issue? String size limit issue? Or something else? 
What is the work around to solve this?

It's almost 18 hours now and I have not found any work around. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: There is no way to answer you based on this information. You have to log some time markers and check what part of code is executing longer than usual or dies. See [Performance Profiling](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html#performance-profiling) in the Guide.

Comment: I would recommend you add the code that generates the pdf content to your question, otherwise there is not really a way we can help you with the information we have.